# Can I setup subdomain.hostname.local on a home network?

Tags: networking, server, localhost, avahi

I have hosts `alpha.local` and `beta.local` running on my home network, the network is managed by a (very) simple wireless router. I can access the servers using, for example, `ssh alpha` or `http://beta.local`. I would like to install services on each so that they are accessible via subdomains, like `http://sub1.alpha.local` and `http://sub2.alpha.local`.

Is it possible to do this, for example with avahi?

Answer (score 1):

simply run this command :

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

then add in all machines in your network, also apply for windows machines:

```
192.168.0.2   alpha.local sub1.alpha.local 
192.168.0.3   beta.local  sub2.beta.local
```

after that you should add sub1.alpha.local and sub2.beta.local aliases in your nginx or apache config file

Answer (score 0):

From the Setting I understand that you dont have a DNS Server in your Network who would resolve Names like `sub1.alpha.local` into its IP Address.
So the usual workaround is configuring the IP manually in your `/etc/hosts` file like

```
192.168.1.101  sub1 sub1.alpha sub1.alpha.local
```

If your router has the DHCP feature you enter the Administrator Panel of your **Router** and set the MAC or Hardware Address of your `alpha` Server manually to be assigned the IP Address `192.168.1.101`

You can find the MAC Address of your Machine with the `ifconfig` command:

```
$ ifconfig
enp4s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.115  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::16da:e9ff:fe96:343e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 14:da:e9:96:34:3e txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 222436  bytes 52837578 (50.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 55928  bytes 7339677 (6.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 529  bytes 15607 (15.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 529  bytes 15607 (15.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It would be the Value

```
ether 14:da:e9:96:34:3e
```

Comment: Setting up multiple alias for the same machine is a quite common problem: [http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1187727] But it seems not possible with `avahi`. Still you can try this Python script: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3896533/7774231]

Answer (score 0):

Better to do this with a trick:
make a symbolic link (folows enabled in config i.e apache) in the directory
example:
/var/www/html/mysite --> you get this if you type the IP from home
/var/www/html/subdomain/ --> this is what you want to
then copy a symlink into the .../subdomain/mysite/ then you can reach it: http://192.168.XXX.XXX/subdomain/ which will do the trick.

I do this way from home, works fine :)

Comment: This is really not an answer to the question, which was explicitly about subdomains.

Comment: This is a workaround for subdomains in home network. If you haven't a special industrial based router, which has a dns record handler, so you are not possible to use subdomain within your home network. That's the truth.